# How to count distinct of record in sql server query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm beginner in sql server and query,i want write query to show me this result:

```
record A count=3
record B count=100
```

for that purpose i write this query:

```
select distinct *from EWSD1
```

but that query show me this result:

```
Record A
Record B
```

but i want show for example record A all field detail and how many repeat in all of the table?thanks.

Comment: `select id, count(/*distinct*/ *) from tbl group by id` ?

Comment: what is name of column A and B

Comment: i have three field on my table,name -adress-postnumber,i want show three field and how many repeat that record in all of the table

Comment: Please add an example table with data and expected results so we can understand exactly what you want.

Comment: try some thing like this `select Name,count(*)  from EWSD1 group by Name`

Comment: @JaydipJ can i write this>>select name,family,adress,count(*) from EWSD1 by name?

Comment: @user3671271 yes but like this `select name,family,adress,count(*) from EWSD1 by name,family,adress`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  [name], -- select the fields you want to see
        [address],
        [postnumber],
        COUNT(*) -- include aggregate
FROM    TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY [name], -- group by fields that aren't inlcuded in aggregate.. 
        [address],
        [postnumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

This will give you the length of the table, a.k.a. how many entry you got in this table

```
COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 3
```

This will give you the number of entries the table "table_name" got where the value of "column_name" is 3. Use `WHERE username LIKE "John"` if you're comparing strings. Simply replace the column_name and table_name by appropriates column name and table name